# How can I backup everything on an android?

Tags: backup, boot-loop, xiaomi, redmi

I have a redmi note 5. It has been asking for updates for a while, which I have been postponing. The reason is that my previous phone, a huawei, got locked into bootloop when I did update it, so I have been weary.

But since I'm starting to cave, I was wondering if there was a way to backup absolutely, utterly everything on the phone, to the point of being able to flash it if I have to, load the data again, and end up holding the exact same phone I did before all that.

Comment: You might need to read *all* the answers on the duplicate first before attempting a backup.

Comment: Well, why do my search skills suck so bad these days? Sorry for the duplicate and thanks!